# How to Use a Colors.ts File React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native. I have a `Colors.ts` file with constants in it:

```
export const orange = '#dd824c';
```

I want to import it in ANOTHER file like this:

```
import orange from '../constants/Colors';
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First way**

Color.ts

```
export default {
   WHITE: '#FFF',
   ORANGE: '#ff9000'
}
```

Import

```
import color from '../constants/Colors';
```

Usage
`color.ORANGE`

```
console.log('COLOR:This is orange color '+ color.ORANGE)
console.log('COLOR:This is white color '+ color.ORANGE)
```

**Second way**

Color.ts

```
export default orange= '#ff9000'
```

Usage

```
 import orange from './../constants/Colors
```

Quick note: Make sure to check correctness of path to your `Color.ts`

Comment: Where do you specify the name `color` when writing `import color...`

Comment: Articulate please, I did not get it

Comment: When you write `import color from "../constants/Colors".` What is the `color` import referencing in `Colors.ts`?

Comment: You can put whatever name you want. For example, 
```import apple from "../constants/Colors".```

Usage ```apple.WHITE``` or ```apple.ORANGE```

Regarding your question. Since we are using ```export default``` we are referring to that object inside ```Colors.ts```. Overall this is name is given to the object inside ```Colors.ts```

Comment: Ohhh I see. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome Raj. Feel free to ask questions

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful! I actually just asked another question and would love your help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63372100/detect-if-no-checkboxes-selected-react-native Thanks!!