# Detect If No Checkboxes Selected React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I made my own `Checkboxes` component in React Native. I want to have a functionality so that **if no checkboxes** are selected, then a button is **disabled**, but when there is **one or more** selected, it is **enabled**. Here is my checkboxes component:

```
const CheckboxList = (props) => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <CheckboxRow title={item.title} checked={item.checked} />
  );
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={props.data}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      style={styles.flatList}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={FlatListDivider}
      scrollEnabled={false}
    />
  );
};
```

UPDATE: here is how the CheckboxList component and button are connected:

```
<CheckboxList
  data={DATA}
/>

<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    navigation.navigate('Screen3');
  }}
  style={styles.button}
  disabled={false}> // make this true if none are selected
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
    Continue
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

As shown above, they are both in the same render.

UPDATE: here is how I update the checked vs. unchecked:

```
const RadioRow = (props) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(props.checked)
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setChecked(!checked)}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons size={40} name={checked ? 'check-circle' : 'checkbox-blank-circle-outline'} color={blue} />
        <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Comment: Bro I actually encourage you to learn React Native. I am mentoring React Native, feel free to reach me out https://www.linkedin.com/in/jasurkurbanovinit/ . My linkedin

Comment: @JasurKurbanov I will certainly reach out!! Do you think you could just help out with this one last thing? I need it for a deadline!! Thanks broooo!!

Comment: Which button are you trying to disable ? can you share the code to see how the button and checkbox are connected

Comment: @RajRentash how do you update the DATA array when an item is checked ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan I updated my answer. Hope this helps. I really, really appreciate your help!!! Thanks!!

Comment: this need a lot of changes, i'll update the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DATA array is getting updated when an item is checked, you can simply do like below. When the selected count is 0 it will disable the touchableopacity

Lets say that you maintain the DATA in state

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    navigation.navigate('Screen3');
  }}
  style={styles.button}
  disabled={DATA.filter(item => item.checked).length === 0}> // make this true if none are selected
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
    Continue
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<CheckboxList
  data={DATA}
  onChange={onChange}
/>
```

You will need an Onchange function to update it from child elements

```
onChange=(id)=>{
  const updatedData=[...DATA];
  const item=updatedData.find(x=>x.id===id);
  item.checked=!item.checked;
  setData(updatedData);
}
```

The other components will take this as a prop and update the parent state

```
const CheckboxList = (props) => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <RadioRow id={item.id} title={item.title} checked={item.checked} onChange={props.onChange}/>
  );
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={props.data}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      style={styles.flatList}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={FlatListDivider}
      scrollEnabled={false}
    />
  );
};

const RadioRow = (props) => {

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.onChange(item.id}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons size={40} name={checked ? 'check-circle' : 'checkbox-blank-circle-outline'} color={blue} />
        <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Comment: I see, will this update in real time? So if a checkbox is selected, it will update the disabled? Thanks!

Comment: Ok - look forward to it. Again THANK YOU so much!!

Comment: One last question! It turns out that I am not updating `DATA`. How could I do this? Thanks!

Comment: you should maintain it in the state like const [data,setData]=useState(DATA); if you data is coming from outside, and you have to use data as the source for the flatlist

Comment: I have to head to bed, but will keep you updated if this works. Upvoted for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219692/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-raj-rentash).

Comment: Shoot, there is actually something that doesn't work. My question is: what is updating the frontend of the checkbox? In `RadioRow` doesn't the `onPress` only update `DATA` not the frontend? Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it, you need to write `props.checked ?...` in RadioRow

Comment: Ok i missed it sorry